# drupal: how to generate doc files in drupal is there any possibility to that

Tags: pdf, drupal, ms-word, drupal-6, drupal-views

how to generate doc file in drupal files..

do we have module for that...
as pdf generation module...

Comment: As in Microsoft Word .doc files?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Views? You might be able to cook up something using the [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) module. It seems a little bit unstable in the export though...

Comment: but with views bonus pack module we can generate only csv files but i need to generate word document files...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.ru/search?q=php+export+doc
In simple way, you can generate just html file, for example via Print module. Microsoft Word will understand it.